# I was stuck when I try to print first index in this function. I don't understand why the white spaces are printed together

Tags: python, function, append

There is the code in the below and I have to solve print error at the very bottom.
I checked a lot about this error but I couldn't find even now.
How can I delete white space which located next to list indexes? **This is the example, I want to change this method**

## ['11', '22', '33'] = > ['11','22','33']

```
def arithmetic_arranger(problems,display=False):

    operators = []
    list1 = []
    list2 = []
    new_list1=[]
    new_list2=[]


    for problem in range(len(problems)):
        if '+' in problems[problem] or '-' in problems[problem]:
            problems[problem] = problems[problem].split(' ')
            list1.append(problems[problem][0])
            operators.append(problems[problem][1])
            list2.append(problems[problem][2])

       
    for problem in range(len(problems)):
        width = max(len(list1[problem]),len(list2[problem]))+2
        new_list1.append(' '*(width-len(list1[problem]))+list1[problem])

    print(list1)
    print(new_list1)


print(arithmetic_arranger(["32 + 698", "3801 - 2", "45 + 43", "123 + 49"]))
```

## ['   32', '  3801', '  45', '  123']

Comment: What's the error?

Comment: Oh! It was just python append's natural operation. By using join method I solved this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
new_list1.append(' ' * (width - len(list1[problem])) + list1[problem])
```

with this part of the code **append(' ' * (** you are telling the program to append to eache list element a number of white spaces equal to the widht minus the lenght of the list1[problem]...
I don't think you can cancel the spaces between the elements of a list